# Sequence of Heads and Tails

Tags: probability

Which one of these is more likely to occur?

A.The sequence H-T-H-T-T-H is more likely to happen than the sequence H-H-H-T-T-T.

B.The sequence H-T-H-T-T-H is less likely to happen than the sequence H-H-H-T-T-T.

C.The sequence H-T-H-T-T-H is equally likely to happen as the sequence H-H-H-T-T-T.

Comment: Site users generally prefer that you show a bit of work for questions like this, otherwise they just feel like they're just being used to do your homework for you rather than actually help you learn.

Comment: @LJL This is me preparing for interviews actually, so I'm going to have to understand the question one way or another. I personally thought the answer was `C` as I feel both sequences are equally likely.

Comment: For independent tosses of a fair coin, each of the $2^6$ possible outcomes is equally likely. The probability of getting exactly 3 heads and 3 tails in any order is ${6 \choose 3}/2^6.$ Is there context to this problem assuring you that the coin is fair and tosses are independent?

Comment: @BruceTrumbo I think we have to assume the coin is fair and independent.

Comment: Then my Comment and the Answer by 'user-whatever' are correct.

Comment: For *independent* tosses of a coin, *fair or not*, the events are equally likely.

Comment: This question probably refers to the mean times before various motives appear, in which case the answer is that these are *not* equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have an unbiased coin ... the probabilities of all answers given would actually be the same.

The probability of flipping a head=probability of flipping a tail= 1/2

Since you flip the coin six times in all of the given scenarios... the probability of all answers is simply $(1/2)^6$

Therefore, all of the given sequences are equally likely to occur. Answer is C.